# CMakeList git clone then add_subdirectory - not working

Tags: cmake, ros-noetic, git

I got this problem where the directory listed on add_subdirectory does not find a CMakeList file and as I checked the folder, it is empty, the package is not yet cloned.
Is there a way where the command add_subdirectory will only process after cloning the package?

Here is my CMakeList:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(test)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(soem
  PREFIX            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies
  GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/OpenEtherCATsociety/SOEM.git
  GIT_TAG           master
  UPDATE_COMMAND    "" 
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_COMMAND     ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
)
add_subdirectory(dependencies/src/SOEM)
```

Here is the log:

```
CMake Error at test/CMakeLists.txt:29 (add_subdirectory):
The source directory

/home/Ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/test/dependencies/src/SOEM

does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/Ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/Ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [Makefile:502: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

Comment: This isn't a ros question it's just pure cmake, you'll have more luck on regular stack overflow (does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307052/cmake-externalproject-add-git help?).  If the outer project is in git is using git submodules an option, and require the user of the outer project to make sure and submodule init?  (I don't particularly like having to do that but I'd prefer it to git clone embedded in cmake)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @LucasWalter, Im sorry that my question is focused on cmake.
Well, adding add_subdirectory after ExternalProject doesnt seem to work since cmake will follow the BUILD,INSTALL_COMMAND so I guess add_subdirectory is a bit redundant.